# Puppeteer selector for dynamically generated span attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to get the text of a span on a Salesforce Lightning page, but on every page the span tag has different attributes.

The element i'm trying to select looks like this:

`<span force-lookup_lookup="" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-9" id="window">SFDC Admin</span>`

So based on this the selector would be `[data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-9"][id="window"]`

However the same span in the same spot (visually speaking) on a different page is:

`<span force-lookup_lookup="" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-17" id="window">SFDC Admin</span>`

Not to mention that `[data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-9"][id="window"]` might contain information from a completely different field on another page.

How can I select this dynamically changing element and save its contents (in this case SFDC Admin) to a variable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `id` is always `window` in your examples. An element's ID _should_ always be unique within a page. Why can't you just select by `id`?

Comment: @Marc Because there are dozens of spans with #window, and I need this specific one. Should have clarified that in my question.

Comment: So I'm really not sure what else there is to select

Comment: There needs to be something to distinguish what you're selecting, e.g., the presence of `force-lookup_lookup` attribute (which... your examples have and you don't indicate their presence on any non-interesting fields), or the sibling elements, or the parent element that contains your desired element, etc.  Otherwise, you might need to know the innerText/textContent, based on context of your execution you're trying to solve.

Comment: if you could compose a wildcard for `aura-pos-lib-*` would that match all occurrences?

Comment: @theDavidBarton Yes, that would also match elements that I'm not interested in. I decided that for starters I should base the selector on the textt as @Marc has suggested since that is the only unique identifier in the span, in combination with the ID and then just return true / false. 

Correct me if I'm wrong but for this I need an XPath? I'm trying to get this working but so far no luck (timeout 3000ms exceeded): 

`"//span[contains(text(), 'SFDC Admin')][@id='window']"`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?